# IBM RFT not recognizing the AUT as WPF(.net application), its considering it as VC++

Tags: wpf, rft

I tried looking up for the doubt i have but didn't find any previous question similar to this.

I am using Rational Functional (IBM RFT) Tester perform some operations on my AUT.
The AUT is a WPF(.net) based application, the pane in my AUT is getting recognized as window class of MFC (i.e VC++ application) and RFT is not able to differentiate the controls that are present in that pane.
However the other pane in the same Application is proper with RFT.

What change i need to do so that RFT recognizes it?
the whole pane is being seen as one object, even when i have combo boxes and button and text boxes present in that pane.
i have tried all the things, recording , adding Data Verification Point but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post Screen shot of the application  , and screenshot of how RFT sees the controls. If the application is WPF based RFT should ideally be able to find the control .. unless  the control in question is some activeX control used for embedding other controls into WPF.

Comment: Hi Prakash,
thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Prakash,
thanks for the reply.
the application we have is on VC++ and the window it launches is based n WPF control. Now RFT is facing problem in recognizing it as a WPF domain.
I have attached the snapshot of the properties that RFT is displaying for the WPF based window.
please let me know if the situation i explained is unclear.

Comment: i have attached snapshots, links are:
1:  http://i60.tinypic.com/2zpp3yp.jpg
           and 
2:  http://i60.tinypic.com/vzzink.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This might turn out to be a limitation or defect. Could you try to use  getChildren() on the control that hosts  the WPF control and see if RFT is able to retrieve any child control? You should report this issue to the RFT support team.

Comment: Thanks again for the response.
The issue is that the WPF window is being recognized as a win domain window (i.e VC++) even though it is created on WPF platform.